# why Airflow Dag Run Id's timezone is not changed?

Tags: docker, airflow

I'm using Airflow based on docker image.

I already set environment

- AIRFLOW__CORE__DEFAULT_TIMEZONE: 'Asia/Seoul'
- TZ: Asia/Seoul

and set volume

- /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro

in **docker-compose.yaml**.

Then I checked datetime(timezone) in all part of Airflow's WEB UI.

Unfortunately, I found only one part is not changed like below:

[image]

Why Dag Run Id's timezone is not changed??

Answer (score 1):

To set the default timezone in the Webserver UI. You may need to set this environment as well:

- name: AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE

  value: "Asia/Seoul"

And, you may need to set the time zone in your DAGs as written in this documentation: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/timezone.html#time-zone-aware-dags

Comment: Turns out someone had the same issue at https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/30645

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I try to set in docker-compose.yaml, AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__DEFAULT_UI_TIMEZONE environment. and I set in dag file, 'start_date': pendulum.datetime(2023, 6, 21, 10, 40, 0, tz="Asia/Seoul"). but nothing is changed...